# Spree Associate user with order with Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, spree-auth-devise

I have a Spree application with the ability to login with Facebook and other social networks , but my problem is that i can't associate user with orders in login , i've tried associate_user! like my following sample but the cart is always empty .

here's my code in omniauthcallback

```
if current_order
    current_user = spree_current_user || @user
    current_order.associate_user!(current_user)
    session[:guest_token] = nil
end
```

Comment: What's the workflow here? A user shops, adds things to their basket, then at checkout they pick "login with facebook" and you want to associate the current order with them?

Comment: Yup , that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out that it's a bug in Spree_auth_devise and it has been solved in version 3.2.0.beta which will be out soon , the problem was in Wardan.rb

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user except: :fetch do |user, auth, opts|
  if auth.cookies.signed[:guest_token].present?
    if user.is_a?(Spree::User)
      Spree::Order.where(email: user.email, guest_token: auth.cookies.signed[:guest_token], user_id: nil).each do |order|
        order.associate_user!(user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You need to remove this part from the code above `email: user.email`